# Implementing Guava's MurMurHash Properly

Tags: java, hash, guava, hashcode

I'm a Junior Java Developer and I'm trying to start a small personal project in order to learn the proper ways to do things (in general). I started searching about `hash()` and while reading an [article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/03/google-guava-5-things-you-never-knew-it-could-do.html) about the benefits of Guava, I stumbled upon `MurMurHash` and the example is very clear on it's [website](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/HashingExplained), but there is something missing that I didn't understand: `Funnel`.

The code goes like this:

```
HashFunction hf = Hashing.md5();
HashCode hc = hf.newHasher()
       .putLong(id)
       .putString(name, Charsets.UTF_8)
       .putObject(person, personFunnel)
       .hash();
```

but then I have to define a Funnel to decompose an object type into primitive field values, for which I have to

```
Funnel<Person> personFunnel = new Funnel<Person>() {
  @Override
  public void funnel(Person person, PrimitiveSink into) {
    into
      .putInt(person.id)
      .putString(person.firstName, Charsets.UTF_8)
      .putString(person.lastName, Charsets.UTF_8)
      .putInt(birthYear);
  }
};
```

Although I searched for more info about how to use this or info in general, there is no clear explanation about how Funnel works and/or how should I use it. Also I don't understand what `PrimitiveSink` is, so I don't know what kind of data should I send as a second parameter.

I would appreciate an explanation o guidance about this.

Comment: Why are you concerned about "what kind of data should I send as a second parameter"?  The API will be calling that method, not you; you don't have to pass that parameter.  (Although the PrimitiveSink that will be passed will be a Hasher.)

Comment: that's what I don't understand, wouldn't I be calling funnel as in `funnel(person, something)`?

Comment: No, you just pass the funnel to the putObject call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually *have* to use a `Funnel` for anything, but a `Funnel` is just an object that expresses how to convert a particular type to a sequence of primitives.  There is no special magic.

```
Funnel<Person> personFunnel = new Funnel<Person>() {
  @Override
  public void funnel(Person person, PrimitiveSink into) {
    into
      .putInt(person.id)
      .putString(person.firstName, Charsets.UTF_8)
      .putString(person.lastName, Charsets.UTF_8)
      .putInt(birthYear);
  }
};
```

This is *just* an object that explains how to convert a `Person` to a sequence of primitives by putting them into a thing that knows how to receive primitives; the interface for things that know how to receive primitives is `PrimitiveSink`.  `Hasher` is an example of a class that implements `PrimitiveSink`, and when you call `hasher.putObject(object, funnelForObjectType)`, the API internally just does `funnelForObjectType.funnel(object, hasher)`, and keeps going.

It's *just* a way of writing a converter from a particular object type to primitives, nothing more.  You are never likely to call `Funnel.funnel` yourself; it's only there to be passed into `putObject` calls; you should never need to pass in your own `PrimitiveSink`.

Comment: so if I override `hashCode()`, it doesn't mean I **have** to override `funnel`?

Comment: `hashCode()` has absolutely nothing to do with any of the Guava hashing APIs.  `funnel` is an interface method; your code won't even compile if you don't override it (if you're using `Funnel` at all, at least).

Comment: I ask because Netbeans automatically overrides `hasCode()` I thought I had to override `funnel()` too.